# Producing an automaton image of my Promela model

Tags: automata, spin, promela, model-checking

I'm using the SPIN model checker GUI - iSPIN. The GUI comes with a nice Automaton view generator, however in order to see the full automaton I need to zoom in/out. Also I would like to save that automaton in a nice image (avoid using print screen) if possible. Is there a way to save the produced automaton image from SPIN, or another tool, that can generate an automaton, based on a Promela model?

PS Below is an image showing the produced Automaton image that I would like to save. Obviously I won't be able to recreate it just by print screen.
[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can use `-D` option with `pan` to generate a file for `dot`. Try:

```
./pan -D > pan.dot
dot -Tps pan.dot -o pan.ps
```

to generate a PS file.